# Logout doesnt seem to work using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Im using the PHP SDK, and after a lot of frustration, I decided to ask the question here.

So here it goes. I made a login button in this website:
http://greek-night.co.uk/

All goes well when you login, but when you try to logout, it always takes me to http://facebook.com/home.php

I have tried everything codewise, and here are some of the examples i tried.

```
first:
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

Second:
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => $base_url.'/'));

Third
$logoutparams = array( 'next' => 'http://greek-night.co.uk/' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($logoutparams);
```

Am I missing anything? I also tried using the 'Debugger' and got this:

```
Application ID  
212442552170234 : Greek Night

User ID 
1112176796 : Michael Schinis

Issued  
1328299200 : 12:00 pm Feb 3 2012

Expires 
1328302800 : 1:00 pm Feb 3 2012
Valid   False
Origin  Web
Scopes  friends_likes read_stream
```

Comment: what's the question? it doesn't log you out? you want it to take you somewhere else instead of the FB home?

Comment: It doesnt log me out, neither does it take me back to the main website, greek-night.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this happened, you should include the JS SDK...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true,});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
});

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

always make your page reload after logout from facebook connect

Comment: hello KYSH, thank you for your response, I will try it out in a bit and let you know, It should work but I was hoping to get it fixed using the php sdk in order to avoid waiting for the JS to load everything. It gets a bit annoying when you are waiting for all the JS to load.